# Importing pure ESM module in TS project fails Jest test with import error

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

Trying to use the [file-type](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type) module which is pure ESM in a TS project but my jest fails. I have set the ESM options as indicated [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/next/guides/esm-support/) but still get a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error.

I have made a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-meadow-vcs0m).

Summary of my code:

```
import { fileTypeFromBuffer } from "file-type";
```

Jest config:

```
export default {
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-node",
  globals: {
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
    "ts-jest": {
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    //"^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1",
  },
  preset: "ts-jest",
  //preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm' // or other ESM presets
};
```

TSConfig:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    //importsNotUsedAsValues
    // "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    // "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",

    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell Jest to transform those ESM bundled libraries with the [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) option.

This options specifies the ignored paths and it defaults to `["/node_modules/", "\\.pnp\\.[^\\\/]+$"]` which explains why the libraries are not being transformed.

The most straightforward solution is to set an empty array:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: []
```

But you could also set a more fine-grained config to exclude everything except some particular libraries, like in the regex example of the docs.

Also, add the `"allowJs": true` option in the TypeScript configuration.

Comment: So almost there. Now I get an error that a package required by `file-type` cannot be found even though I see it in node_modules. `Cannot find module 'strtok3/core' from node_modules/file-type/core.js`

Comment: It might be related to a bug in `file-type`. `strtok3` exists but not `strtok3/core`, the right import seems to be `strtok3/lib/core` like reported in this issue: https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/pull/513

Comment: Oh OK I got it, I think it's `ts-jest` not taking this configuration into account in `strtok3` `package.json`: `"exports": { "./core": "./lib/core.js" },`

Comment: Are you thinking this is a ts-jest bug to be reported then?

Comment: To be honest I did not dig deep enough yet to determine if this is a bug or a configuration option but I suspect that it is not yet supported as the ECMAScript modules support is experimental